# Axios CORS not working on chrome deployed site

Tags: amazon-s3, axios, cors

I have the following method in a VueJS application:

```
const downloadImageBase64 = async imageUrl => {
  try {
    var result = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: imageUrl,
      responseType: 'blob',
      crossdomain: true
    });

    return blobToBase64(result.data);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err);
    return "";
  }
};
```

I am downloading images and returning them as a base64 strings because I'm embedding them into PDF's that I'm creating using JSPDF. The images themselves are hosted in AWS S3. I have the CORS policy set up in the appropriate S3 bucket:

```
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "https://mydomain.co.za"
      "http://localhost:8082"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
  }
]
```

When running the app on my localhost, the image download succeeds with both FireFox and Chrome:

[image]

However, the moment I deploy the app to my staging environment, the download starts to fail with CORS issues, but only on Chrome. Looking at the request headers, no CORS info is even being sent:

[image]

I don't know if there's a preflight that Chrome is not showing in the network traffic, but the console gives me the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my-bucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-image-path.png' from origin 'https://mydomain.co.za' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the issue is that I display the images on the webpage where the download PDF button is placed, which means that chrome caches these images and when attempting to download the images for the PDF, chrome is returning the cached images without the CORS headers. I more or less got the answer from here:

https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handle-images-cors-error-in-chrome

So the solution is to append a throw-away get parameter to the URL when downloading for the PDF:

```
const downloadImageBase64 = async imageUrl => {
  try {
    var result = await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `${imageUrl}?not-from-cache-please`,
      responseType: 'blob',
      crossdomain: true
    });

    return blobToBase64(result.data);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err);
    return "";
  }
};
```

Note the:

```
url: `${imageUrl}?not-from-cache-please`
```

Comment: It's incredible how a simple parameter makes us lose days of work.